# How to upgrade Ubuntu release while keeping versions of already installed packages

Tags: upgrade

Sometimes it's important to keep current versions of already installed packages when upgrading Ubuntu release, let's say, from `12.04` to `14.04`.

I don't emphasize if it's `server` or `desktop` assuming this procedure should be same.

Standard release upgrade steps are:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo do-release-upgrade

But this will upgrade packages as well.
Is there a way to keep versions of already installed packages?

**UPDATE 1**:

- I will perform release upgrades remotely, so I will a need command line solution.
  It's possible to check versions using `dpkg`, `apt-cache policy` (and maybe with `aptitude`, haven't tried yet).
- I won't have any packages in remote computer's repository. I will just need to specify what versions I need and it will download that required packages.

I feel like I will need to write a custom script to solve this issue, but it doesn't seem the best way - packages will be upgrading along with a release upgrade and then I will downgrade them. It'd be nice if I were able to install/keep required version during a release upgrade process.

Comment: Have you looked at the Synaptic Package Manager? Will that not do what you require?

Comment: Hi. I will update my post later today. I'm looking for command line solution.

Comment: Do you try to keep the packages (eg. the deb-files) or are trying to keep the binaries installed and have them available to run them side-by-side with the new version?

Comment: @MadMike I have updated my post.

Comment: You can mark packages to hold, Similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) I don't know how well the upgrade will go if you hold a key package.

Answer (score 1):

you would be best downloading the packages and saving them to a USB or CD/DVD Rom for install at a later date.