# Prevent new Ubuntu upgrade to reinstall MySQL

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to the next version seems to reinstall Mysql. Any way to ignore MySQL install during OS Update?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/592138/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-release-while-keeping-versions-of-already-installed-packag By the way, 11.04 [crossed the EOL line](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-October/000165.html) more than 5 years ago!

Comment: Please kindly backup data and re-install fresh your system is EOL for over 5 years and a lot would have changed since then

Answer (score 2):

if you want to avoid that `apt-get upgrade` update certain package, you can "hold" it in the following way:

Hold a package (do not upgrade):

`sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>`

disable hold (upgrade package the usual way):

`sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>`

for MySQL:

`sudo apt-mark hold mysql-server`

Comment: So I run this command then the upgrade one

Comment: Error: first argumente must be markauto, unmarkauo or showauto

Comment: Never had such issue before. On my Mint18  works just fine:

`user@server ~ $ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-server
[sudo] password for user: 
mysql-server set on hold.
`